# Referrer URL from facebook form POST

Tags: php, facebook, forms, post

I'm posting a form from a Facebook application to a form processor on my web server and then redirecting to a thank you page.

I want to ensure nothing else can post to this form so was looking to restrict it to only receive input from the Facebook app. The problem I'm coming up against is when I try to find the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it isn't passed from Facebook. The value isn't even null, it's not even shown.

Is there anything else I could possibly use to lock down this form processor?

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through the referer, nor through anything FB will send you, since FB doesn't send anything except if a user has installed your app.

What you can do is use an antiforgery token, since you're serving the initial form itself.  I think this example is pretty decent:
http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: Thanks for your response Paul. It seems that it's not possible to use sessions within facebook apps.

Comment: Actually it seems that sessions are fine, so long as you stay within the facebook domain. I was trying to post to an external site with a FQDN, if I just post to /processor.php it works fine. Thanks for your help Paul.